# How can i create a login popup in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, prism

I am using Prism For wpf application. I want to create a login popup that opens before the main shell. and if user enters his credentials successfully then the shell opens up and the popup should be closed. currently i have created another window for login.

[Here is the login Window that opens on startup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oShFP.png)

In the Command Method i am doing this.

```
private void LoginToApplication() {
    Shell mainWindow = new Shell();
    Login loginPopup = new Login();
    loginPopup.Close();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

but i dont like a multiwindow app. just want a popup so any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: A pop up does not need to open other window. both windows will be visible but the shell will be blur until user doesnt login.

Answer (score 1):

This is what regions are for. You should create a second region in your main window in front of all its other regions (call it "DialogRegion" for example). To show the login dialog, just navigate the dialog region to the login dialog. When the dialog is closed, clear the dialog region. The blurring or shading of the area "outside" the active dialog could be in the style of the dialog region's hosting content control or just in the login dialog itself.